# Is there any way to var_dump a variable?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to var_dump a variable to debug my database operation. I don't want to install any debugger so I used var_dump($result) in my model. It output the errors.

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can use [CI's logging facility](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html):

```
log_message('debug', var_export($some_variable));
```

And check your application's log folder, usually application/logs. You can do that anywhere - model or controller.

NB - Check application/config/config.php to ensure logging is enabled. It's not simply a on/off switch, you can choose the level of logging messages to record. Set to all for development but to errors only on production, for example.

Comment: My bad, I did a header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'); in constuctor of the controller. When I var_dump, I always get the error "Extra content at the end of the document code igniter".

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result to the controller - then do a var_dump($result) inside the controller.

I've noticed a few times that you cant var_dump() from a model.